# SOAP php client : blank request

Tags: php, soap

im trying to use the php soap client to make a soap call, but it keeps giving me " Request cannot be blank. Please provide request details. ". What am I doing wrong here?

```
  $username = 'myusername_example';
    $password = '123456787';


    $url = "http://trail.dexceldesigns.com/m2m/APIwsdls/SessionService/SessionService.wsdl";
    $soapclient = new \SoapClient($url);

    try{
        $params = array(
            'Username' => $username,
            'Password' => $password
        );
    $response = $soapclient->LogIn($params);
    }
    catch(\SoapFault $fault)
    {
        echo '<br/>'.$fault->getLine();
        echo '<br/>Message: '.$fault->getMessage();
        echo '<br/>Trace: '.$fault->getTraceAsString();
        echo '<br/><br/>'.$fault->getCode();
        echo '<br/><br/>'.$fault->getFile();


    }
    var_dump($soapclient->__getLastRequest());
```

EDIT:
Output for var_dump($soapclient->__getLastRequest()); is always coming as NULL

EDIT:2 (this is the request according to the documentation)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NPhase.UnifiedWebService.APIs.v2.Contract.SessionService" xmlns:ns2="http://nphase.com/unifiedwebservice/v2">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:LogIn>
      <ns2:Input>
        <ns1:Username>?</ns1:Username>
        <ns1:Password>?</ns1:Password>
      </ns2:Input>
    </ns2:LogIn>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: does the end point "trail.dexceldesigns.com" expect something more than just username and password?

Comment: @Dagon the endpoint doesnt require anything as far as I know. I've added the xml request that im supposed to generate